# Compress an existing large CSV file with Python using GZIP in low memory machine

Tags: python, compression, gzip

I'm trying to take an existing csv file on a small windows 10 vm that is about 17GB and compress it using gzip.
Its too large to read into memory.

Looking for ways to do this efficiently that doesn't involve partitioning the file.

This is what I'm trying right now and its quite slow:

```
import gzip
import shutil

with open('file_to_be_compressed.csv', 'rb') as f_in:
    with gzip.open('test_out.csv.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

EDIT:
This is part of a pipeline where I'm downloading the data from one source and uploading it to another. The upload will be much faster if I can compress the files first (unfortunately they weren't already compressed on the source side).
So I have code that pulls a list of files, and for each file I'd like to compress it and then I'll upload it.

Comment: Which operating system? Do you want to keep the original file? This is usually done with a external utility. `gzip thefile.csv` would compress to `thefile.csv.gz` and delete the original.

Comment: I don't need to keep the original file. I added an edit to elaborate. I just need these files to be smaller to allow for a faster upload to a cloud bucket.

Comment: You're compressing 17 GiB with gzip using maximum compression level. Based on various benchmarks, you can expect compression speed around 10MiB/s, so overall time to compress the file can be expected to be around half an hour. Reduce the compression level -- going down to something like level 6 is going to result in marginally worse compression ratio, and it will be 2-3x faster.

Comment: You could use subprocess to call gzip externally. That will be faster than going through the python code. Although likely marginally faster. Compression takes ttime.

Comment: @tdelaney I doubt that's gonna make any difference, the bottleneck is bound to be GZip, not Python or IO. I even tested it locally, the difference between running the Python script and just using gzip on command line with identical compression level is about 0.2 seconds.

Comment: I suppose calling some parallelized version of gzip (like pigz) on the command line might make a difference, but then again, this is a resource limited VM, so who knows if OP even has more than one CPU core allocated to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are downloading a large .csv, you would ideally like to compress it *on the fly*, and upload the compressed version.

If that's right, then you do not need to write either the uncompressed or compressed data to files. You can instead download a piece at a time, compress  as you go along, and upload the compressed data.

To do that, use [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html). Create a `zlib.compressobj()` object, with a `wbits` value of `31`, to select the gzip format. Let's say you call that object `gz`. Then use `gz.compress(data)` for each chunk of the .csv you download. Upload the result returned by each `gz.compress(data)`. When the download is complete, upload the result of `gz.flush()` to complete the compressed data.